# Building a get-ChildItem query with variables for filepath and filename

Tags: powershell

Currently my code is something like this:

```
$filedir = "$env:HOMEDRIVE\temp\ps\"
$fileName = $window.TxtName.Text
$result = Get-ChildItem -Path $filedir -Include $fileName| Where-Object {$_.extension -eq ".txt"} 
$result
```

Whilst I build on my local machine - the actual code will be using a UNC share.

I cannot get the Get-ChildItem to allow for a variable for the -Include.

The end result is to take the `$filedir` and `$fileName` from user input, grab the file and attach the file to an email.

Comment: Tried the following too; no luck. `$filedir = "$env:HOMEDRIVE\temp\ps\"
$fileName = $window.TxtName.Text
$watermark = Get-ChildItem -Path $filedir | Where-Object {$_.extension -eq ".txt" -and $_.name -like $fileName}
$watermark`

Comment: Why not simply `Get-ChildItem -Path $filedir -Include "$fileName*.txt"`

Comment: The `$fileName*.txt` doesn't pick up all matching files - i'm now doing ` $result =  = $filedir + '$fileName* ` which works for 1 file, but I need it to pick up all matching files with  `$filename*.txt`